# Cant use SetVar with PostAdd or PreAdd hooks PDM Api

Tags: c#, solidworks

I'm working with **SolidWorks PDM 2017 SP5**

Hello, I am working on an Add-in that must modify a variable when the documents are added to the vault, the problem, is that both, `PreAdd` and `PostAdd` return me an error that the document was not checked out by me (*0x080040210*), obviously, the files have not been registered yet

This is my code

```
public void GetAddInInfo(ref EdmAddInInfo poInfo, IEdmVault5 poVault, IEdmCmdMgr5 poCmdMgr)

        {

            poInfo.mbsAddInName = "Titulo C# Add-In";

            poInfo.mbsCompany = "ARTRANS S.A.";

            poInfo.mbsDescription = "Renombra los títulos de las obras de epdm.";

            poInfo.mlAddInVersion = 1;

            poInfo.mlRequiredVersionMajor = 17;

            poInfo.mlRequiredVersionMinor = 5;

           //Create PreAdd hook (with PostAdd i have the same result)

            poCmdMgr.AddHook(EdmCmdType.EdmCmd_PreAdd);

        }

public void OnCmd(ref EdmCmd poCmd, ref Array ppoData)

{
 switch (poCmd.meCmdType)    
 {    
        case EdmCmdType.EdmCmd_PreAdd:    

            IEdmVault5 _Vault = (IEdmVault5)poCmd.mpoVault;

            IEdmFile5 archivo = default(IEdmFile5);

            var varManager = default(IEdmEnumeratorVariable8);    

            foreach (EdmCmdData fila in ppoData)

            {

                archivo = (IEdmFile5)_Vault.GetObject(EdmObjectType.EdmObject_File, fila.mlObjectID1);

                varManager = (IEdmEnumeratorVariable8)archivo.GetEnumeratorVariable();

                varManager.SetVar("Title", "", "Example"));

                varManager.CloseFile(true);

            }

            break;   
    }    
}
```

Someone knows how it must be done? i'm really out of ideas!

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the documentation about **[EdmCmdData Structure](http://help.solidworks.com/2017/english/api/epdmapi/epdm.interop.epdm~epdm.interop.epdm.edmcmddata.html)** with the behavior of EdmCmdData Structure on each hook, so, in my case, with `PostAdd`

I got

ID of parent folder **in** `EdmCmdData.mlObjectID1`

Local file path **in** `EdmCmdData.mbsStrData1`

And with the required data i just replace this line:

```
archivo = (IEdmFile5)_Vault.GetObject(EdmObjectType.EdmObject_File, fila.mlObjectID1);
```

For this

```
IEdmFolder5 carpeta = (IEdmFolder5)_Vault.GetObject(EdmObjectType.EdmObject_Folder, fila.mlObjectID1);
archivo = _Vault.GetFileFromPath(fila.mbsStrData1,out carpeta);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to handle PostAdd, and make sure the file is checked out by you on your machine.

```
IEdmVault12 _Vault = (IEdmVault12)poCmd.mpoVault;
// Get our userId
var userId = _Vault.GetLoggedInWindowsUserID(_Vault.Name);
IEdmFile5 archivo = default(IEdmFile5);
var varManager = default(IEdmEnumeratorVariable8);
foreach (EdmCmdData fila in ppoData)
{
    archivo = (IEdmFile5)_Vault.GetObject(EdmObjectType.EdmObject_File, fila.mlObjectID1);
    // Make sure we're the user with the file checked out and it's checked out on this machine.
    if (archivo.LockedByUserID != userId || archivo.LockedOnComputer != Environment.MachineName)
        continue;

    varManager = (IEdmEnumeratorVariable8)archivo.GetEnumeratorVariable();
    varManager.SetVar("Title", "", "Example"));
    varManager.CloseFile(true);

}
```